# ExtJS 3.* chart uses too much memory

Tags: extjs, memory-leaks, charts, extjs3

I am using Ext JS line chart with over 5000+ data. It uses too much memory especially on IE. How can I fix this leak or why it causes?

Comment: Is there a necessity for showing that much data at one time? Can you aggregate any data points on the server to reduce the amount of rendering that has to occur?

Comment: I think it is necessary show all data. How can I aggregate on the server side?

Comment: You're data is coming from the server, correct? So in the process that returns the result to ExtJS, have a method which first processes the data and aggregates it, then return the aggregate data to your chart.

Comment: Yes, coming from server. I have a method on server side, I am calling this method with ajax request and returns a large json, after that I will put data to my chart. Is it same what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both displaying 5k+ data points and processing it on client side are bad design decisions and should be avoided. Nobody can possibly comprehend this much data in one chart; that should be 10-12 points max or it becomes meaningless white noise. Client side processing in JavaScript is **expensive**, especially in older IEs; not only that, but you're also wasting time and resources transferring the data that is not going to be used.

The best solution is to modify your server side method to filter or aggregate data and provide UI access to these features.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have same Question , I do agree its not worth loading that much data but there are cases where I need to show drilling data in my ExtJs window.

Whose image is displayed below :

[image: Logviewer for Drilling Data]

Here the points may go upto 15k data. Actually user wants to see the variations here rather than actual data. But he may need mouse over / zoom .

I achieved this with HTML5 plugin and adding this as an iframe.

Any words to achieve in ExtJs or how to go for this.

Comment: When you start talking about this much data, regardless of graphing library you need to start defining some restrictions.  e.g. only so much data on the screen at any given time, modern browser only, do as much calculations on the server side as possible, allow drill down to make subsequent calls to the server for more information rather than preloading that data.

Comment: Ya agreed Phil,
But when user wants to go for charts they want too much data as they are worried about the change happened and when ... not the exact value.

Say for example Yearly report , here I can't tell like you have to take 12 reports on monthly basis... !
There he cant compare and contrast...